# Replacing a variable by its exact value (not expanding) in bash

Tags: bash, variables, replace

I have written a script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

opt1='-vvaumrhhhsq --info=name1 --delete --modify-window=2 --safe-links'
opt2="--progress --exclude-from=$HOME/exrsync"
opt3='--exclude-from="$excl" --log-file="$logfile"'

src="$HOME"
dest="/My Backup/home/"    
excl="$HOME/exrsync-gh"
logfile="rsync_home.log"

rm -f "$logfile"
rsync ${opt1} ${opt2} ${opt3} "$src" "$dest"
```

**Based on `bash -x myscript.sh` output:**
`opt1` varibale has nothing to be expanded, i.e.:

```
 + opt1='-vvaumrhhhsq --info=name1 --delete --modify-window=2 --safe-links'
```

`opt2` is expanded on the line it is defined, i.e.:

```
+ opt2='--progress --exclude-from=/home/username/exrsync'
```

and `opt3` is not expanded in the line it is defined, i.e.:

```
+ opt3='--exclude-from="$excl" --log-file="$logfile"'
```

But in the last command of the script, `opt1` and `opt2` are replaced by their values without `''`, but each part of `opt3` is putted inside single quotes, i.e.:

`+ rsync -vvaumrhhhsq --info=name1 --delete --modify-window=2 --safe-links --progress --exclude-from=/home/me/backup/rsync/exrsync` **`'--exclude-from="$excl"' '--log-file="$logfile"'`** `/home/me '/My Backup/home/'`

Obviously above command will return an error:

```
rsync: failed to open exclude file "$excl": No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at exclude.c(1179) [client=3.1.0]
```

I need that `opt3` to be raplaced such as `opt1` is replaced. Thus the last command will be as follows:

`+ rsync -vvaumrhhhsq --info=name1 --delete --modify-window=2 --safe-links --progress --exclude-from=/home/me/backup/rsync/exrsync` **`--exclude-from=/home/me/exrsync-gh --log-file=rsync_home.log`** `/home/me '/My Backup/home/'`

**Note:**
One solution is to put `opt3` definition after `excl` and `logfile` definitions, so it coulde be expnded in the line it is defines. But I do not want to do that, because in the future I want to add some loops to above script and in this way I have to re-define `opt3` every time `excl` or `logfile` change.

Comment: The single quotes aren't the problem. That's just `-x` telling you those are literal strings in a way that makes them safe to be a command you run by hand. The problem is that variable expansions aren't recursive like that. The shell doesn't expand variables in the result of an expansion. You need to not do that and/or force the shell to do that with `eval`/etc.

Comment: Why is setting the value of `opt3` in the loop a problem?

Comment: @chepner Because I have to be curious about where an when `excl` and `logfile` are changing in my script and adds some extra effort if the script becomes somewhat complex. But is the single solution I found until now!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using arrays to store program arguments. You also need to define `logfile` and `excl` *before* you use them to set the value of `opt3`.

```
#!/bin/bash

src="$HOME"
dest="/My Backup/home/"    
excl="$HOME/exrsync-gh"
logfile="rsync_home.log"

opt1=(-vvaumrhhhsq --info=name1 --delete --modify-window=2 --safe-links)
opt2=(--progress --exclude-from=$HOME/exrsync)
opt3=(--exclude-from="$excl" --log-file="$logfile")



rm -f "$logfile"
rsync "${opt1[@]}" "${opt2[@]}" "${opt3[@]}" "$src" "$dest"
```

---

One thing you *can* do is wrap your `rsync` command in a function that will take two arguments, the value of `excl` and the value of `logfile`.

```
syncer () {
    excl=$1
    logfile=$2
    shift 2
    options=( --vvaumrhhhsq
              --info=name1
              --delete
              # etc
    )
    rsync "${options[@]}" --exclude-from="$excl" --log-file="$logfile" "$@"
}

syncer "$excl" "$logfile" "$src" "$dest"
```

Comment: Thank you for offering array, but I know that if `excl` and `logfile` are defined before `opt3` there is no problem. I need the solution that lets me to define `excl` and ``logfile` after `opt3`.

Comment: There is no such solution. `bash` doesn't perform recursive lookups on parameters stored in the value of `opt3` when expanding it.

Comment: Thanks again, I am new to `bash`.